# prevent clang from generating sret instructions

Tags: clang, llvm

Is there a way to tell clang to not use struct return (sret) instructions? I only plan to analyze the generated LLVM bitcode and not execute it so it doesn't matter if the struct gets too big to be returned directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clang generates `sret` in order to satisfy the requirements of platform ABI, so in general you cannot turn this off. You can try to generate the code for the different target platform, however, I'm not aware of any allowing arbitrary structs to returned directly.